# /stats meta data missing

Tags: bug, status-completed

So am I to assume that since we can make an extra call to another site to get meta that site node in stats has been deemed redundant data.

If so, I have to suggest a reality break. This is one of several instances where the over aggressive conservation of a few bytes of bandwidth adds workload and complexity to consuming systems.

I realize we are in beta and changes are to be expected but please keep in mind the amount of time and effort the *unpaid* developers who are, as I have mentioned before, driving exposure to your brand.

Can we get just a little more love paid to the old school notion of adding to an interface wont break implementations, deleting from an interface breaks everything.

```
{
 "statistics": [
  {
   "total_questions": 737715,
   "total_unanswered": 117069,
   "total_answers": 2030194,
   "total_comments": 2888132,
   "total_votes": 7146491,
   "total_badges": 737025,
   "total_users": 265568,
   "questions_per_minute": 1.85,
   "answers_per_minute": 3.73,
   "badges_per_minute": 1.56,
   "api_version": {
    "version": "0.8",
    "revision": "2010.6.17.1"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed.